# Switching to multi-part cloud-init, getting: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

I used to have

```
user_data  = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
```

I changed that to,

```
user_data  = data.template_cloudinit_config.master.rendered
```

And I added,

```
data "template_cloudinit_config" "master" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  # get common user_data
  part {
    filename     = "cloud-init.cfg"
    content_type = "text/part-handler"
    content      = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
  }
}
```

But now I'm getting this error, in my `cloud-init.log`

```
2022-07-12 15:19:21,514 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/1a6e9475-5d46-4b3f-b7bc-642055614e22/handlers/part-handler-000.py - wb: [600] 16701 bytes
2022-07-12 15:19:21,514 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed at registering python file: /var/lib/cloud/instances/1a6e9475-5d46-4b3f-b7bc-642055614e22/handlers/part-handler-000.py (part handler 0)
2022-07-12 15:19:21,514 - util.py[DEBUG]: Failed at registering python file: /var/lib/cloud/instances/1a6e9475-5d46-4b3f-b7bc-642055614e22/handlers/part-handler-000.py (part handler 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/handlers/__init__.py", line 144, in walker_handle_handler
    mod = fixup_handler(importer.import_module(modname))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/importer.py", line 15, in import_module
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/var/lib/cloud/instances/1a6e9475-5d46-4b3f-b7bc-642055614e22/handlers/part-handler-000.py", line 3
    users:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, nothing changed in that file. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was I had

```
content_type = "text/part-handler"
```

I should have had,

```
content_type = "text/cloud-config"
```

---

For more information:

- https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html